# I don't know what condition to write when the connection is closed

Tags: python, sockets, if-statement, module

I want to write a condition to establish the connection when my connection is disconnected. For example, when the connection is connected, when it is disconnected, the connection should be established again.

**Sample_code:**

```
import socket

REMOTE_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
REMOTE_PORT = 2222
client = socket.socket()

print("Wating...")
client.connect((REMOTE_HOST,REMOTE_PORT))
print("Done...")
```

**here**

```
if client == ?? :

 client.connect((REMOTE_HOST,REMOTE_PORT))
```

Please help me...

Comment: Maybe this could be of help? https://instructobit.com/tutorial/101/Reconnect-a-Python-socket-after-it-has-lost-its-connection

Answer (score -1):

For the backend side, once it yields the exception, you would disconnect it. For the client side, you would use exceptions to handle the disconnect situation or use the regular ping pong to update the connection status. Behind the socket, the client side and server side will regularly ping-pong each other to ensure the connection validly, I suggest you monitor the connection status with try to catch rather than send out the regular msg to update the status.

Below websocket was written by python and handle the exception with JWT and WebsocketDisconnection

```py
@router.websocket("/spotlight_dating/ws/chat/")
async def websocket_endpoint(
    websocket: WebSocket,
    X_Spotlight_AccessToken: str=Header(...),
    User_Agent: str=Header(...),
    db: Session = Depends(appConfig.sqlDB),
):
     isTokenValid, secureId, accessToken = authHandler.isTokenValid(X_Spotlight_AccessToken, True)
     accessToken = accessToken
     user = db.query(UserModel).filter_by(secureSpotlightId=secureId).first()
     hadDuplicateMobileLogIn = mongoDBManager.hadDuplicateMobileLogIn(user.secureSpotlightId)          
     if webSocketManager.isUserExist(user.socialToken):
          await webSocketManager.sendErrorMsg(
               webSocketManager.getRefWebSocket(user.socialToken),
               {
                    'type': '[Error]',
                    'msg': 'Duplicate Login', 
               },
          )
     await webSocketManager.connect(websocket, user.socialToken)
     if isTokenValid:
          isAccessTokenValid = mongoDBManager.isAccessTokenValid(user.secureSpotlightId, accessToken)
          print(f"isAccessTokenValid:{isAccessTokenValid}")
          if isAccessTokenValid:
               try:
                    while True:
                         data = await websocket.receive_text()
                         jsonData = json.loads(data)
                         cTime = str(timeConverter.now())
                         receivedUser = db.query(UserModel).filter_by(socialToken=jsonData['receivedId']).first()
                         await webSocketManager.sendMsg(
                              websocket,
                              receivedUser.secureSpotlightId,
                              jsonData['receivedId'], 
                              {
                                   'msg': str(jsonData['msg']),
                                   'time': cTime,
                                   'sender': str(user.socialToken),     
                              },
                         )
               except WebSocketDisconnect:
                    print("User Close WebSocket")
                    webSocketManager.disconnect(websocket, user.socialToken)
          else:
               print("Token Not Valid")
               webSocketManager.disconnect(websocket, user.socialToken)               
     else:
          await webSocketManager.sendErrorMsg(
               websocket,
               {
                    'type': '[Error]',
                    'msg': 'Token has expired', 
               },
          )
          webSocketManager.disconnect(websocket, user.socialToken)
```

Comment: I don't want this script for the web, I want it to communicate between two computers.It should not be interrupted for a moment.
But thanks again for your advice